# Get path of notebook in Github on Google Colab

Tags: python, github, google-colaboratory

I am opening a notebook in Colab from Github. In Github, the path to the notebook is:

src/dir/notebook.ipynb

When I open it Colab, how can I get this path? The only path I get upon instatiaiton in Colab is:

/content

Thank you

Comment: Can you try cloning the repo in your google drive and then mount the drive in colab?

Comment: Unfortunately, I need a solution where drive is not installed. One way would be to get the fileId, but I am having trouble with that